# register crontab using text file on www-data account

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

Trying to register crontab using text file, but cronjob Is in www-data account.

What I tried is

`sudo -u www-data crontab.bak | crontab -`

However it doesn’t work. I wonder if this is possible to register crontab using text file on www-data account.

Comment: If something "doesn't work", you need to tell us *how* it doesn't work. Show us the error message, if any. `sudo -u www-data crontab.bak` will attempt to execute the *command* `crontab.bak` under the `www-data` account. Presumably that's not what you want to do.

Comment: there are many crontab jobs in crontab.bak, but none of them registered in crontab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo -u www-data crontab.bak | crontab -
```

I'm assuming that `crontab.bak` includes the crontab entries that you want to add to the crontab for the `www-data` account. (You didn't clearly say that in your question.)

This command:

```
sudo -u www-data crontab.bak
```

attempts to run the command `crontab.bak` under the `www-data` account. Since `crontab.bak` is not a command, that doesn't work. It should give you an error message like

```
sudo: crontab.bak: command not found
```

-- which you should have included in your question.

Furthermore, the `sudo` applies only to the first command in your pipeline. In general, if you do

```
sudo -u www-data command1 | command2
```

it will run `command1` under the `www-data` account, but it will run `command2` under your account. It's the `crontab` command that you want to run as `www-data`.

If the `www-data` account has permission to read the `crontab.bak` file, you can do this:

```
sudo -u www-data crontab crontab.bak
```

If not, you'll have to read the file from your own account and feed the output to the `crontab` command running under the `www-data` account:

```
cat crontab.bak | sudo -u www-data crontab -
```

Or, since this is a [Useless Use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html):

```
sudo -u www-data crontab - < crontab.bak
```

To be clear, in this final version the `crontab` command runs as `www-data` and reads from its standard input, and the redirection `< crontab.bak` is handled by the shell running under your account.